# Laravel 9 - name of image does not get saved in the database, while the image saves

Tags: laravel, database, image, store, laravel-9

The image is getting succesfully saved, the imageName is getting created, but when I try to save imageName in the image name, it shows as NULL. The odd thing is that whatever I write for that column, it still shows as NULL. The image column in the database is a simple varchar (250) column. What's wrong? I can't figure out.

```
       if($request->hasfile('file')) {

        $image = $request->file('file');

        $imageName = time() . '.' . $image->getClientOriginalExtension();

        $request->file = $imageName;

        $car = new Car([
            'brand' => $request->brand,
            'model' => $request->model,
            'fuel' => $request->fuel,
            'consumption' => $request->consumption,
            'body'=> $request->body,
            'seats' => $request->seats,
            'transmission' => $request->transmission,
            'year' => $request->year,
            'price' => $request->price,
            'image' => $request->file
        ]);

            Image::make($image)->resize(500, 500)->save(public_path('/images/cars/' . $imageName));
            $car->save();
        
    }

    return response()->json('Car successfully added');
```

Comment: does assigning a name manually work? Also, ``$request->file = $imageName;`` doesn't make any sense, directly use the ``$imageName`` variable and pass to the image propert of he car object ``'image' => $imageName``

Comment: Adding in the car objected any name manually for the image column doesn't work. And yes, I know, I tried to use $request->file for storing to test if it would work "by magic".

Comment: add your car model class file code.

Comment: probably you missed adding the image column to the fillable variable within your car model.

Comment: You were right! Thank you so much. I'm actually working on a project of a friend, I didn't know he hasn't added the image column as well to the $fillable

Answer (score 0):

Please check your Model it should be something like this:

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Crud extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = [
            'brand' ,
            'model' ,
            'fuel',
            'consumption' ,
            'body',
            'seats',
            'transmission' ,
            'year' ,
            'price',
            'image',
       ];
}
```

/////DO NOT FORGET TO CHANGE Crud EXTENTION WITH YOUR MODEL NAME/////